# How to run an audio and gdi effect in python without audio cutting

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, gdi, winsound

I made a python script that runs a GDI PATCOPY effect. I wanted to add audio while it works so I used python's `winsound` module for making beeps and python's `Threading` module to run the GDI effect and the beeping at the same time, however when I run the script 90% of the beeps made with the audio is cut out or silenced, how do I fix that silencing?

This is my code right now:

```
from threading import Thread

import os    
from win32gui import *
from win32api import *
from win32ui import *
from win32con import *
from random import *


def func1():
    #sound generator
    import winsound

    freq = 500         
    dur = 1000
    freq1 = 600
    dur1 = 200
    freq2 = 100
    dur2 = 100
    freq3 = 900
    dur3 = 120
    freq4 = 700
    dur4 = 3000
    freq5 = 9000
    dur5 = 100
    freq6 = 5000
    dur6 = 500
    freq7 = 700
    dur7 = 700
    freq8 = 900
    dur8 = 400
    freq9 = 300
    dur9 = 900 
    winsound.Beep(freq, dur)
    winsound.Beep(freq1, dur1)
    winsound.Beep(freq2, dur2)
    winsound.Beep(freq3, dur3)
    winsound.Beep(freq4, dur4)
    winsound.Beep(freq5, dur5)
    winsound.Beep(freq6, dur6)
    winsound.Beep(freq7, dur7)
    winsound.Beep(freq8, dur8)
    winsound.Beep(freq9, dur9)

def func2():
    for i in range(1):
        desk = GetDC(0)
        x = GetSystemMetrics(0)
        y = GetSystemMetrics(1)
        print(x)
        print(y)
        #os.startfile('guiCorrupt.py')
        for i in range(50000):
            brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(
                randrange(255),
                randrange(255),
                randrange(255)
                )) #Creates a brush
            SelectObject(desk, brush) #Choose that we're drawing with our brush.
            PatBlt(desk, randrange(x), randrange(y), randrange(100), randrange(200), PATCOPY)
            DeleteObject(brush)
            #Sleep(1) #wait
        ReleaseDC(desk, GetDesktopWindow())
        DeleteDC(desk) #Deletes our DC.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
```

I think it has something to do with the GDI effect itself because without running the effect, I can hear the beeps just fine without any silencing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try playing a wav file instead of the individual notes

EDIT:
.wav files are large real GDI Malware uses bytebeat for the sounds
here's a repo for python https://github.com/Itzsten/Python-ByteBeat

and some samples: https://dollchan.net/bytebeat/#

Comment: Can you elaborate?